# How to copy an existing Arduino library in order to modify it?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I want to modify an existing Ardiuno library. Let's call it foo. I create a directory for a sketch and create a file test_foo.ino. I include foo

```
#include "foo.h"
```

then write my test code.
If I compile this, it works fine.

Now I copy foo.h and foo.cpp into my sketch directory. foo is mostly a class definition. I compile and get lots of errors about duplicate symbols. So now I change my file my_foo.h and my_foo.cpp and

```
#include "my_foo.h"
```

compile again - same errors, with the symbols defined once in my_foo.cpp, and once in foo.cpp in the libraries directory.

It seems that all installed libraries are compiled by default and linked against my sketch.

Obviously I can work around this problem by changing the name of the class in foo.[h,cpp], but that's pretty clunky. Is there a way to prevent the linker from trying to include the existing copy of the library?

Because the backend build of VS Code is the same as the Arduino IDE, I have the same problem in both.

Comment: do you have a 'header guard' ifdef?

Comment: yes, I do. But that's not the problem. The problem is that the code in my directory is compiled and then linked against essentially everything in the Arduino/libraries directory, which includes the original version of the library which contains the same symbols. The linker the complains about duplicate symbols. Since the problem is at the linker symbol level, changing file names won't help.

Comment: Firstly, you were right there I rename the files at least since otherwise Arduino IDE will see both and give you a conflict from that perspective. I assume nowhere in your code you still include the original header as well. After that, does the Arduino IDE have a "clean build" option? I haven't used the IFE on awhile as I now use PlatformIO, which has a command to clean (remove) all the build.oroducts and build fresh.

Comment: it is not a problem of IDE or builder. search for error in your code